# Нужно ли выделить "как прежде" и  "кроме того" запятыми?

Tags: пунктуация

Полнота может привести к снижению самооценки, кроме того, полная женщина эмоционально чувствует себя более скованной в постели, возможно, она, как прежде не будет себя чувствовать сексуальной и привлекательной, что и отрицательно влияет на половую функцию женщины. А у мужчин половая функция имеет более физиологический характер и психологическое состояние имеет меньшее значение.

Answer (score 0):

*кроме того* выделяется запятыми, так как здесь это вводное сочетание. 
*как прежде* всегда выделяется запятыми, так как это сравнение.